# SQL Server NULL Integer to Empty String using ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string, isnull

My curiosity always gets the best of me and I've searched online for an explanation to this and came up with nothing (could be because I didn't use the right terms.)

Can someone please explain why SQL Server returns a value of zero (0) when the following is executed, instead of an empty string ('').

```
    DECLARE @I AS INT
    SET @I = NULL
    SELECT ISNULL(@I, '') -- 0
```

Comment: SQL Server is implicitly casting '' to an integer, which is 0 (zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As declared [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), the second argument to `ISNULL` is the replacement_value, which "must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of check_expresssion." Implicitly converting `''` to `INT` results in 0.

Comment: Uh, the value '' IS implicitly convertible. It casts as 0. select cast('' as INT) -- returns 0

Comment: Thanks.. Looks like the answer was right under my nose.

Answer (score 2):

Because @I is declared as an `INT`, the empty string is implicitly CAST as an integer resulting in a ZERO.

Comment: have the same issue. Hope somebody will propose better solution then changing source column data type. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937037/convert-int-column-values-to-an-empty-string-using-isnull

Answer (score -2):

I know is an old question, but I want to share.
The issue here is not because the casting of the `' '` expression, is because the **int** data type is **not null-able** and, when you try to `SET @I = NULL` SQL set the default value zero(0).
That's why the statement `ISNULL(@I, '')` does not find any null in `@I` and returns its value(0).

Hope it helps somebody out there.